# Способ передачи аргументов для функции и методов Python

Tags: python, методы, функции

Друзья, особенно те, кто программирует на Python, хотел бы обсудить следующий вопрос, который, как мне кажется в бОльшей степени относится к вопросам начинающих, но всё же. Мне бы хотелось услышать некоторые пояснения или рекомендации: в каком случае какой способ передачи аргументов при вызове функции или метода лучше использовать и/или используйте Вы в своих проектах. И как Вы решаете, как вообще объявлять функцию. Ниже приведён небольшой пример:

```
def foo(id, name, age, email):
    print id
    print name
    print age
    print email

foo(101, 'Max', 19, 'max@somedomain.org')
print '------'
foo(id=101, name='Max', age=19, email='max@somedomain.org')
print '------'

def bar(**kargs):
    print kargs['id']
    print kargs['name']
    print kargs['age']
    print kargs['email']

bar(id=101, name='Max', age=19, email='max@somedomain.org')
```

Функция `foo` объявлена стандартным способом с аргументами `id`, `name`, `age`, `email`.
Функция bar объявлена немного иначе, точнее способ передачи аргументов здесь с помощью `**kargs` (про `*args` я тоже в курсе, но решил здесь не приводить как пример)
Самая банальная рекомендация, которая следует из моей логики такова: когда непонятно количество аргументов функции (было бы здорово привести примеры из реальных проектов когда так) или очень много аргументов - лучше использовать **kargs. Но при этом, как мне кажется есть один минус, в плане самодокументируемости кода. Т.е. чтобы понять какие аргументы можно передать в функцию нужно чтобы был написан docsting (или просто сторонняя документация) или следует изучать реализацию функции и на основании её уже делать выводы, что передавать можно, а что нельзя. Извиняюсь за некоторую сумбурность вопроса, но надеюсь суть того, что я спрашиваю я изложил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле args и kargs я использую только для парсинга параметров командной строки (ну это и так понятно). Остальные функции делаю исключительно как foo (может у меня просто не было функций с огромным количеством параметров).

```
def collect_object(client, param_object, view, args, wait_thread = None, stdin_passwd = False):
```

Хотя нет, нашёл даже вот такую:

```
def set_paths (cls, data_path, certbase, serv_certbase, rights, \
               group_rights, sids, pids, sids_pids, cert_path, log_filename, \
               cert="server.crt", key="server.key"):
```

Это помогает при изменении параметров, так как я не пропущу эти параметры при вызове функции. Да и наглядность, самодокументируемость. А насчёт "когда непонятно количество аргументов функции" - у меня такого не было пока. К тому же многие ide подсказывают, какие параметры не используются, что тоже иногда полезно=)

Comment: Спасибо. Вот касамо IDE, когда с помощью intelli-sense отображается метод или функция с args и kargs приходится либо смотреть исходники, либо документацию.

Comment: Да, особенно неприятно это, если необходимо быстро внести небольшую правку в код, который не видел пол года.

Comment: у меня такое встречается, когда работаю с wxPython или matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

Бывают случаи использования и `*args` и `**kwargs`. С ходу вспомню только django — там через kwargs реализован запрос к базе данных.

```
users.objects.filter(name='Иван', birdthday__year=1985)
```

Естественным образом функция filter получает аргументы через `*args` и `**kwargs`, причем, как мне помнится, одновременно и через `*args` и через `**kwargs`. Не помню, как там точно сделано.

Что до различия

```
foo(101, 'Max', 19, 'max@somedomain.org')
```

и

```
foo(id=101, name='Max', age=19, email='max@somedomain.org')
```

второй способ имеет смысл, когда аргументы предопределены. К примеру:

```
def foo(id=0, name=None, age=20, email=None):
    # some magic

foo(name="Max", email="max@example.com")
```